# Не выводит заданное количество строк

Tags: python, python-3.x

Изучаю `Python` и возникла небольшая проблема с таким упражнением(изучаю по книге Саммерфильда - "Программирование на `Python3`. Подробное руководство")

Само упражнение сократил но задание можно понять
И так из 4 уже заполненных списков(артикль,существительное,глагол,наречие) сгенерировать предложения с помощью 5 циклов,`random.choice()`. В таком полученном стихе 5 строк,и в каждой строке такие вот случайно подобранные предложения.

Что было сделано мной

-Созданы 4 списка, переменная `line=5`(количество строк)

-Цикл `while` с таким условием пока `line!=5` выполнять

-В самом цикле уже внутренние циклы перебора значений каждого списка,выбор какого-либо из них с помощью `random.choice()` и вывод на экран.

Проблема следующая:

Я работаю в `Ubuntu` и с помощью терминала запускаю своё мини-приложение но оно не запускается,а просто происходит перенос на следующую строку в терминале(как будто команда выполнилась-см. рисунок)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Код:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random
import sys

listarticles=["the","a","for","an","this","that","those"]
listsush=["cat","dog","man","woman","duck","girl","boy"]
listglag=["sing","walk","run","drink","eat","sleep","cry"]
listnarech=["loudly","fastly","well","badly","quietly","ugly","blackly"]

line = 5
while line!=5:
     for ls1 in listarticles:
        ls1 = random.choice(listarticles)
        print(ls1)
     for ls2 in listsush:
        ls2 = random.choice(listsush)
        print(ls2)
     for ls3 in listglag:   
        ls3 = random.choice(listglag)
        print(ls3)
     for ls4 in listnarech:
        ls4 = random.choice(listnarech)
        print(ls4)
     line+=1
```

Comment: `line = 5`
`while line!=5:`
А таки чего вы ждёте?

Comment: Но это только одна ошибка, вторая ошибка будет в том, что некорректно находятся слова для этого стиха

Comment: Настоятельно рекомендую вам научиться пользоваться отладчиком. Они встроены во все современные IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задание, то вам нужно, что-то такое

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
import sys

listarticles = ["the","a","for","an","this","that","those"]
listsush = ["cat","dog","man","woman","duck","girl","boy"]
listglag = ["sing","walk","run","drink","eat","sleep","cry"]
listnarech = ["loudly","fastly","well","badly","quietly","ugly","blackly"]

line = 0
while line != 5:
    ls1 = random.choice(listarticles)
    print(ls1, end=" ")
    ls2 = random.choice(listsush)
    print(ls2, end=" ")
    ls3 = random.choice(listglag)
    print(ls3, end=" ")
    ls4 = random.choice(listnarech)
    print(ls4, end=" ")
    print()
    line += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно слегка упростить код, используя цикл, чтобы 5 предложений составить:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random

articles = ["the", "a", "for", "an", "this", "that", "those"]
nouns = ["cat", "dog", "man", "woman", "duck", "girl", "boy"]
verbs = ["sing", "walk", "run", "drink", "eat", "sleep", "cry"]
adjectives = ["loudly", "fastly", "well", "badly", "quietly", "ugly", "blackly"]

parts = articles, nouns, verbs, adjectives 
for _ in range(5):
    print(*map(random.choice, parts))
```

`map` вызывает `random.choice` функцию для каждого списка, представляющего часть предложения:

```
print(*[random.choice(part) for part in parts])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import random
import sys

listarticles=["the","a","for","an","this","that","those"]
listsush=["cat","dog","man","woman","duck","girl","boy"]
listglag=["sing","walk","run","drink","eat","sleep","cry"]
listnarech=["loudly","fastly","well","badly","quietly","ugly","blackly"]

line = 0
while line!=5:
    ls1 = random.choice(listarticles)
    print(ls1, end=" ")
    ls2 = random.choice(listsush)
    print(ls2, end=" ")
    ls3 = random.choice(listglag)
    print(ls3, end=" ")
    ls4 = random.choice(listnarech)
    print(ls4, end=" ")
    print()
    line+=1
```